When I click on the push notification on my android app, entire app reloads
I have a React Native app with RN version "react-native": "0.72.7", and use react-native-notification with version ^5.1.0 for my push notification service for both Android and iOS applications.
The push notification service works fine in iOS without any issues. The push notification service for the Android app has some problems.
I am dealing with a reloading issue for the Android versions 11 and above. Following is the scenario for the bug.
Steps

Open the Android app and keep it in the background
Receive notification for the app and click on the notification from the notification center
The app will open but the entire application gets reloaded

Accepted Criteria

The app should not reload when clicking on the push notifications

Can anybody give me some sense into why this is happening?

How do you know "entire application gets reloaded"? What have you done to debug this? What does "notification details are not viewed properly" mean? Why does your app care if the app is in the background or starting fresh? You should be able to handle either scenario, no?

When the app opens after clicking on the push notification the app reloads. I can see the splash screen and everything.
I am using Raygun with logging information for the analyses and logs & there are no crash reports or other issues mentioned in the Raygun logs.
My issue is this only happens in Android 11 & above. Older versions app open and view the notifications as it should.

Did you check in the release build? I think this issue is only in debug build.

Yea, issue came through the release build in production and now I managed to re-create this in dev

It is hard to suggest a solution without a code or some log messages.
Probably if you use adb logcat you could see some useful log messages that would help with this issue. But, I managed to find something related to your issue here.
First, try updating your targetSdkVersion to 33, and see if it solves your problem. You can find it on your android/app/build.gradle file, for example:
[...]
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 33 <--- here
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
}
[...]

After this, re-compile your app and test it.
If it doesn't help, you should try to make changes on the following files (- means you will remove it, + means you will add it):

/node_modules/react-native-notifications/lib/android/app/src/main/java/com/wix/reactnativenotifications/RNNotificationsModule.java:

//[...]     
     @Override
     public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
         if (NotificationIntentAdapter.canHandleIntent(intent)) {
-            Bundle notificationData = intent.getExtras();
+            Bundle notificationData = NotificationIntentAdapter.extractPendingNotificationDataFromIntent(intent);
             final IPushNotification notification = PushNotification.get(getReactApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(), notificationData);
             if (notification != null) {
                 notification.onOpened();
//[...]                      


/node_modules/react-native-notifications/lib/android/app/src/main/java/com/wix/reactnativenotifications/RNNotificationsPackage.java

//[...]
         Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
         if (NotificationIntentAdapter.canHandleIntent(intent)) {
             Context appContext = mApplication.getApplicationContext();
-              Bundle notificationData = NotificationIntentAdapter.cannotHandleTrampolineActivity(appContext) ?
-                    NotificationIntentAdapter.extractPendingNotificationDataFromIntent(intent) : intent.getExtras();
+            Bundle notificationData = NotificationIntentAdapter.extractPendingNotificationDataFromIntent(intent);
             final IPushNotification pushNotification = PushNotification.get(appContext, notificationData);
             if (pushNotification != null) {
                 pushNotification.onOpened();
//[...]


 /node_modules/react-native-notifications/lib/android/app/src/main/java/com/wix/reactnativenotifications/core/NotificationIntentAdapter.java

//[...]
     @SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag")
     public static PendingIntent createPendingNotificationIntent(Context appContext, PushNotificationProps notification) {
-        if (cannotHandleTrampolineActivity(appContext)) {
-            Intent mainActivityIntent = appContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appContext.getPackageName());
-            mainActivityIntent.putExtra(PUSH_NOTIFICATION_EXTRA_NAME, notification.asBundle());
-            TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(appContext);
-            taskStackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(mainActivityIntent);
-            return taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
-        } else {
-            Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, ProxyService.class);
-            intent.putExtra(PUSH_NOTIFICATION_EXTRA_NAME, notification.asBundle());
-            return PendingIntent.getService(appContext, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
-        }
+        Intent intent = appContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appContext.getPackageName());
+        intent.putExtra(PUSH_NOTIFICATION_EXTRA_NAME, notification.asBundle());
+        return PendingIntent.getActivity(appContext, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
     }

     public static boolean cannotHandleTrampolineActivity(Context appContext) {
//[...]     

After these changes, re-compile your app and test it.
These changes are not permanent, so to make them permanent you will need:

Fork the react-native-notifications module on your GitHub account
Make these changes on your fork.
Uninstall the original react-native-notifications module by running: npm uninstall react-native-notifications
install your fork by running: npm install git+https://github.com/yourUsername/YourForkNameHere

Hope it helps.

Yea, I understand. I found the solution for this in a patch
